# Redux.js: Trouble rendering array of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux

I had an action make an api call to a backend to retrive an array of objects. The action then dispatches an update to a state variable. At this point I meet the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {x, y}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The following code has been minimized to still produce the error:

```
getDonationData : (reportType, recordCount) => (dispatch => {
    return Axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/reports/`,
      {
      reportType, recordCount
    }
    )
      .then(apiResponse => {
        const returnedArray = apiResponse.data;
        dispatch({
          type : 'reportData',
          payload : [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 3}]
        })
      })
  })
```

If the objects in the array are replaced by numbers like `[1, 2, 3]` the error goes away.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to work around the possible nesting limitation? My actual data has about 500 items and the x values are also date objects (this is chart data).

Reducer code:

```
case 'reportData':
      return {
        ...previousState,
        reportData : action.payload
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is might from component where you are accessing `reportData`, may be you are trying to display object (`ex. {x:1, y:2}`) from `reportData` instead of single data (ex. `x`).

Comment: You are correct, it was in the prop passdown that the error was being raised:  `reportData={this.props.reportData}`